# Understanding python slicings syntax as described in the python language reference

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

The following is the slicings syntax that I copied from [The Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings):

```
slicing      ::=  primary "[" slice_list "]"
slice_list   ::=  slice_item ("," slice_item)* [","]
slice_item   ::=  expression | proper_slice
proper_slice ::=  [lower_bound] ":" [upper_bound] [ ":" [stride] ]
lower_bound  ::=  expression
upper_bound  ::=  expression
stride       ::=  expression
```

Per my understanding, this syntax equates to `SomeMappingObj[slice_item,slice_item etc...]` which again equates to something like `a[0:2:1,4:7:1]` and `a =[i for i in range(20)]`.

But, I can't test this in IPython and I did not find any questions about multiple slicings. Is my interpretation about multiple slicing in python correct? What am I doing incorrectly?

```
In [442]: a=[i for i in range(20)]

In [443]: a[0:12:2]
Out[443]: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

In [444]: a[0:12:2,14:17:1]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-444-117395d33bfd> in <module>()
----> 1 a[0:12:2,14:17:1]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: what are you expecting as an output for `a[0:12:2,14:17:1]`?

Comment: That is what I wanted to find out. From the syntax, it seems to be a valid operation. Common sense would make me guess the result as [0,2,4,6,8,10,14,15,16].

Comment: For your purpose use `a[0:12:2] + a[14:17:1]`

Comment: I have to say, this question is much more insightful than the title initially led me to expect. Nice work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `slice_list` should contain as many "dimensions" as the object being indexed. The multi-dimensional capability is not used by any Python library object that I am aware of, but you can test it easily with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
a[0:1, 0]
```

There are a number of such features in the Python language that are not used directly in the main library. The `__matmul__` magic method (`@` operator) is another example.

Comment: I would not say that the slice_list has anything to do with "dimensionality". Rather, it has to do with how many arguments `__getitem__` accepts (see the answer from @chepner).
You could have a subtype of `list` which accepts any number of slices, and creates a resulting list containing all the values indexed by every value in each slice_item.

Comment: @AisteruFirë. Partially agreed, hence the "scare quotes" around dimensions. I used that term loosely, since arrays are the place I see multiple slices used most commonly. That being said, `__getitem__` technically only accepts one argument. It's the implementation's job to check if that item is a tuple or something else.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the grammar is structured this way to allow two things:

1. A family of `slice` literals:

   1. `x:y:z == slice(x, y, z)`
   2. `x:y == slice(x, y, None)`
   3. `x: == slice(x, None, None)`
   4. `x::z == slice(x, None, z)`
   5. `::z == slice(None, None, z)`
   6. `:y:z == slice(None, y, z)`
   7. `:: == slice(None, None, None)`
   8. `:y: == slice(None, y, None)`

   There are a few other patterns possible (`x:y:`, `:y`, etc), but each
   is a variation on one of the above.
2. Slice literals may *only* be used inside `[...]`, not in any arbitrary expression.

Otherwise, the comma-separate list is treated like any other tuple. When you write an expression like `f[1, 2:3, 5::7]`, then `f.__getitem__` receives a tuple `(1, slice(2, 3, None), slice(5, None, 7)` as its argument. What `f.__getitem__` *does* with that argument is entirely up to `type(f)`'s implementation of `__getitem__`. For instance, lists and strings only accept `int` and `slice` values as arguments, and dicts only accept hashable values.

Answer (score 1):

That's valid syntax, so you didn't get a SyntaxError. It's just not a meaningful or supported operation on Python lists. Similarly, `"5" + fish` isn't a SyntaxError, `1/0` isn't a SyntaxError, and `I.am.a.monkey` isn't a SyntaxError.

You can't just expect all syntactically valid expressions to be meaningful.

Comment: Might be  'not supported operation' but I question 'not a meaningful operation' part. If I want to extract the slice [0,2,4,6,8,10,14,15,16] from a, the easiest and most obvious way is to have multiple slices. I am not sure if something not supported would make it to the language syntax specification. Can you please provide any reference?

Comment: @sudheernalubolu: You're assuming that comma-separated slices mean something completely different from what they actually mean. As vishes_shell said in the comments, you want `a[0:12:2] + a[14:17:1]`. Comma-separated slices are for multidimensional objects.

Comment: @sudheernalubolu The *grammar* allowing any `primary` to be sliced is what allows you to define `__getitem__` for any class. The parser first has to allow the expression before you can define the semantics. Extended slice notation simply isn't defined for any builtin type.

Comment: (Ignore the last sentence in my comment above; it's just wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a syntax issue hence no `SyntaxError`, *this syntax is totally supported*. `list`'s just don't know what to do with your slices. Take for example a dummy class that does *nothing* but define `__getitem__` that receives the contents of subscriptions `[]`:

```
class DummySub:
    def __getitem__(self, arg):
        print(arg)

f = DummySub()
```

It just prints its `arg`. We can supply slices, as permitted by the grammar, but, *it's up to the implementing object to decide if these are an operation* that's supported and act on them (like `nparray`s do) or not (and raise a `TypeError`):

```
f[1:2:3, 4:4:4]
(slice(1, 2, 3), slice(4, 4, 4))
```

Heck:

```
f[1:2:3, 4:5:6, 7:8:9, ...]  # totally valid
(slice(1, 2, 3), slice(4, 5, 6), slice(7, 8, 9), Ellipsis)
```

By reading further on in the [*reference for slicings*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings) you should see that:

> The semantics for a slicing are as follows. The primary is indexed (using the same `__getitem__()` method as normal subscription) with a key that is constructed from the slice list, as follows. *If the slice list contains at least one comma, the key is a tuple containing the conversion of the slice items*; otherwise, the conversion of the lone slice item is the key.

<sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup>